# Can an anonymous inner class, created by an abstract enclosing class, determine the implementing class via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

The short form of the question is:

- abstract class A1
- abstract class A2 that creates an anonymous inner A1
- Class A3 extends A2 - can an instance of A1 created by A2 know it was created within A3?

Fleshing out the question:

Lets say i have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Abstract1 {}
```

Then I have a second abstract class that can create instances of Abstract1:

```
public abstract class Abstract2 {
    protected Abstract1 createAbstract1() {
        return new Abstract1() {};
    }
}
```

Third, I have a concrete implementation of Abstract2:

```
public class Concrete extends Abstract2 {}
```

Lets put some print statements into Abstract2:

```
public abstract class Abstract2 {
    public Abstract1 createAbstract1() {
        System.out.println("I am: " + getClass().getName());
        Abstract1 a1 = new Abstract1() {};
        System.out.println("A1 is enclosed by: " + ab1.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getName());
        return a1;
    }
}
```

When we construct `Concrete` and ask for an A1 as follows...

```
Concrete charlie = new Concrete();
Abstract1 myA1 = charlie.createAbstract1();
```

...we see the following output:

```
I am: Concrete
A1 is enclosed by: Abstract2
```

How can myA1 know it was created by a Concrete instead of an Abstract2?

Comment: Pretty sure it's not possible. Objects don't keep a reference to the class they were instantiated from. You would have to explicitly pass `this.getClass()` into the `Abstract1` constructor.

Comment: Objects don't *in general* keep track of the object, if any, whose method instantiated them, but instances of inner classes are most often instantiated by the enclosing instance of their enclosing class, and they *do* keep a reference to their enclosing instance.

Comment: is there any simple technique for an instance of an anonymous inner class to refer to the object in which it was created?

Comment: Yes, @RichardSand; any inner class can refer to its enclosing instance with a class-qualified `this`.  In your example, that would be `Abstract2.this`.  And it can obtain that object's class by invoking its `getClass()` method.  But that probably doesn't help you for accessing any of that information from outside.

Comment: Abstract2.this gives an error for no instance, I think because class Abstract1 is not defined inside class Abstract2

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. See example:

```
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Concrete charlie = new Concrete();
        Abstract1 myA1 = charlie.createAbstract1();
        myA1.printOuter();
    }
}

abstract class Abstract1
{
    abstract void printOuter();
}

abstract class Abstract2
{
    public Abstract1 createAbstract1()
    {
        System.out.println("I am: " + getClass().getName());
        Abstract1 a1 = new Abstract1()
        {
            @Override
            void printOuter()
            {
                //We can access instance of outer class by "Abstract2.this" 
                System.out.println("My outer class: " + Abstract2.this.getClass().getName());
            }
        };
        System.out.println("A1 is enclosed by: " + a1.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getName());
        System.out.println("Real class of this: " + getClass().getName());
        return a1;
    }
}

class Concrete extends Abstract2
{
}
```

I added `printOuter` method if you really want to get it from inner class, not the method which create it.